# Is there any way to enclose a variable with print() statement or any function in vim especially using vim vs code extension

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, vscodevim

suppose I have a variable named

```
a_variable
```

is there a surround or some combination of keystrokes which will do

```
print(a_variable)
```

or

```
print("a_variable: ", a_variable)
```

when my cursor in on the line where `a_variable`  is defined ?
I could not find any relevant material on the web .
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers is written with Vim in mind. Some, all, or none of it may apply to your specific Vim *emulator* so YMMV.

### With [the surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround)

#### First case

You can position your cursor on `a_variable` and do:

```
ysiwfprint(<CR>
```

to obtain:

```
print(a_variable)
```

#### Second case

It is currently impossible to achieve with surround only.

### Without surround

#### First case

You can position your cursor on `a_variable` and do:

```
ciwprint(<C-r>")<Esc>
```

#### Second case

The scond case is a variant of the first case where you insert the variable name two times instead of one:

```
ciwprint("<C-r>": ", <C-r>")<Esc>
```

Turn it into a mapping if you need to do it often.

See `:help c`, `:help iw`, `:help i_ctrl-r`, `:help ""`.

Comment: in the `ysiwfprint(<CR>` what does `f` do here ?

Comment: The basic use case for that surround plugin is adding/changing/removing surrounding pairs like `()`, etc. The `f` is one added functionality that is [described](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/master/doc/surround.txt#L138) in surround's documentation.

Comment: thanks, it cleared my doubt regarding `f` still have no luck doing this operation in vscode vim.

Comment: As noted, everything with `ysiw` above depends on a Vim plugin that definitely works in Vim once you have installed it. I know some Vim *emulators* include a re-implementation of surround… maybe your specific Vim *emulator* does, maybe it doesn't, maybe it does but it is incomplete, etc. I have no idea. Everything with `ciw` above is vanilla Vim and is guaranteed to work even in the smallest Vim builds, without any plugin. But again, there is no guarantee that your Vim *emulator* supports any of that.

Comment: `ysiw` works fine but `f` puts be back in normal mode. :(. Thanks for the help though. I have just started learning vim so started learning with vscode extension.

Comment: I'd recommend learning $THING with $THING.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239303/discussion-between-sanket-wagh-and-romainl).